# How do you change the color of a cursor so you can see it on a black background?

Tags: text-editor

I'm using TextEdit to transcribe sections of 26 moleskine notebooks that I've filled up over the past 7 years. I changed the background to black and the text color to gray, which is great for the eyes except I cannot see the cursor. This makes it hard to edit, as you can imagine. When I use textwrangler or sublime the cursor blinks white..how do I extend these settings to textedit?

Thank you - first ever stackoverflow question :)

Comment: Yes! This is one of those things that I can't believe is happening. Why isn't the cursor color locked-in with the text color?  Sigh.  It's Apple: "Do it our way or the highway."  They've become the stony Big Brother they made fun of in 1984.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like TextEdit does not allow configuring the color of the cursor.

[Is there a way to change the cursor color in TextEdit?](https://discussions.apple.com/message/4108756#4108756)